# Keycloak: All API response with 404

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

I followed this [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-keycloak) to setup Keycloak and create user but the response for the  step of Generating Access Tokens With Keycloak's API 404. I'm using Keycloak version 18.0.0

In the logs of keycloak I found this error

```
2022-06-12 23:59:57,177 DEBUG [org.keycloak.services.error.KeycloakErrorHandler] (executor-thread-3) Error response 404: javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: RESTEASY003210: Could not find resource for full path: http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/test/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

[image]

Comment: Without your endpoint-code it is hard to determine. Maybe the REST-Method is not post? Or something in the path is wrong?

Comment: I has no code. It just a setup from keycloak admin console

Comment: The URL for generation token in Keycloak is http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/ {{realmName}}/protocol/openid-connect/token

Comment: Are you sure it is configured to run on port 8080? the tutorial is running on a different port

Comment: I can access the admin console using this url http://localhost:8080

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**404 Error means the URL of the resource does not exist.**

You did set in Headers instead of Body.
Move the Key & Values to Body.[image]

#### In Keycloak version 18

You can verify Token URL by click "OpenID Endpoint Configuration" link
[image]

It will show Token URL
[image]

#### In Keycloak version 21

[image]

##### OIDC Well-Known Configuration Endpoint

Returns the OpenID Connect configuration values from the
Keycloak's Well-Known Configuration Endpoint

```
GET /.well-known/openid-configuration
```

```
http://localhost:8080/realms/[your realm]/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

##### Token End Point

```
http://localhost:8080/realms/[your realm]/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

[image]

Get `Access Token` by Postman.
[image]

Comment: I moved them and still got 404

Comment: As @Abhijeet have mentioned you need to remove the auth

Comment: Thanks @dreamcrash, I added a picture how to verify Token URL.

Answer (score 9):

From keycloak 17+ there are changes in resource or token URIs. Try removing `auth` from your request URL.

If you are using Keycloak version < 17

`curl -k -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "client_id=your-client" -d "username=some-user" -d "password=hardpassword" -d "grant_type=password" -X POST http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/yourrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token`

If you are using Keycloak version > 17

`curl -k -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "client_id=your-client" -d "username=some-user" -d "password=hardpassword" -d "grant_type=password" -X POST http://localhost:8080/realms/yourrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token`